# Combine CSV files and remain the first two letter of the name

Tags: batch-file

I need to combine .csv files but remain the original name.

I have various .csv files with the following names

```
01-15 Codes.csv
01-85 Codes.csv
01-30 Codes.csv
```

I made a search and I can achive it easly using the following code in a Batch File

```
@echo off
copy *.csv Combined.csv
```

But I need something more complex. Because I need the code respect the name of the combined files.
For example, If I use the code

```
@echo off
copy *.csv 01.csv
```

For the files above in the example, all the file will combine in one file called "01.csv" but this name is because I edited it in the code. I need a code that renames the combined file based on the group of files.

For example, I have the following files:

```
02-15 Codes.csv
02-85 Codes.csv
02-30 Codes.csv
```

I need the resulting file is called "02.csv"

Or if I have the following files:

```
07-15 Codes.csv
07-85 Codes.csv
07-30 Codes.csv
```

I need the resulting file is called "07.csv"

I mean, it changes the name based on the numeration. I need a code that can conform to all the combinations. It would be a code that retains the first two letters of the original csv files (before combining them) because all the csv files have the numeration in the beginning and with two digits, example: 01, 02, 03.....15, 18, 35.

I can't edit the batch code each time I'll combine the .csv files based on the name of the group of file, but that's not the idea.

Thank you so much!

Comment: hi please add appropriate tag like unix or power-shell or cmd so that we know the language.

Comment: @Rex5 - [batch-file] is the name of the language (or rather, "batch" is the name of the language, but [batch-file] is its tag).

Comment: With PowerShell it can be a one liner (with aliases): `gci [0-9][0-9]-*.csv| group {$_.Name.substring(0,2)+".csv"}|%{$_.Group|gc|Set-Content $_.Name}` But the resulting combined csv files aren't valid if they contain multiple headers from the source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split the file names at the hyphen `-`. The following stores every individual prefix in an array-like variable `$PREFIXES[]`:

```cmd
for /F "delims=- eol=-" %%I in ('dir /B "??-*.csv"') do set "$PREFIXES[%%I]=%%I"
```

You can then walk through these variables or pseudo-array elements and do the actual copying/merging:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=2 delims== eol==" %%J in ('set $PREFIXES[ 2^> nul') do copy /B "%%J-*.csv" "%%J.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /L %%a in (0,1,9) do for/L %%b in (0,1,9) do if exist "%%a%%b-*.csv" copy "%%a%%b-*.csv" "%%a%%b.csv"
```

should combine all ??-*.csv files into ??.csv for every 2-digit combination 00..99

Note that if the destination file already exists,this will prompt to overwrite the existing file